# "Eundem"/"eumdem" in medieval Latin

Tags: language-evolution, medieval-latin, declension, orthography

"Eundem" is the correct accusative of "idem". However, I saw "eumdem" in various texts of medieval and/or Church Latin. So I wonder:

- when did "eumdem" start to be used, perhaps by non-native Latin users?
- when did it become a regularly accepted alternative to "eundem" (this might not be distinguishable from previous subquestion though)?
- did "eumdem" ever completely replace "eundem" in some time and region (not counting times/regions with very few written records)?

Comment: This is an example of phonological dissimilation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissimilation)—in this case, the dental consonant [n] dissimilating from the dental consonant [d] to become the labial consonant [m]. But I don't know the answer to your question, and I can't even think of an example in English, so I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer. :)

Comment: Another keyword is [*sandhi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi). A classical example being words like *symbiont (syn-biont).*

Comment: @Joel Derfner: I’d rather say _eundem_ is an example of assimilation, because the “expected” form would indeed be _eumdem_ (compare _eum_). There was lots of variation in whether this assimilation appeared in writing or not, especially visible with the prefix _in-_ (_im-_, _ir-_, _il-_, _i-_)

Comment: @chirlu Hmm. I'm not sure I agree. If it were "eunbem," then "eumbem" would be the expected form. but [d] and [n] are both dentals, whereas [m] is labial.

Comment: @Joel Derfner: Are you aware that the first part of _eundem_ is _eum_, with the _-m_ being the accusative ending?

Comment: @chirlu OH CRAP I'M A MORON. Sorry. I wasn't thinking. Bleah.

Comment: @chirlu No more than I deserve for privileging phonology over morphology. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the texts stored in the [Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/) as a guide, we can see that the prevalence of *eumdem* waxes and wanes through history.  Its earliest significant use in writing appears to be approximately the 4th century, and it reaches its height in the late Medieval period, but even then it does not displace *eundem*.

## Earliest usage

Several works from the post-classical era employ *eumdem* rather than *eundem*; here are some examples:

- Lactantius, *[Divine Institutes](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/lactantius/divinst1.shtml)*, 7 instances in Book I
- The abridgement of Livy's [Ab Urbe Condita Libri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_Urbe_Condita_Libri_(Livy)), the *Periochae*, is thought to date to the 4th century ([30](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/livy/liv.per30.shtml), [59](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/livy/liv.per59.shtml), [85](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/livy/liv.per85.shtml))
- Augustine uses *eumdem* in several of his sermons, for example,  [2](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/augustine/serm2.shtml), [15](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmgO3S7KnLAhUlsoMKHQtLD7I4ChAWCE8wBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thelatinlibrary.com%2Faugustine%2Fserm15.shtml&usg=AFQjCNEsi4HoxbBk8GUNwfSdV6il-rtBvg&sig2=p8MBZyFPoMt5tnIvvfcTdw), as well as other works, like [*De Fide et Symbolo*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/augustine/fide.shtml)
- Festus's [*Summary*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/festus.shtml) has one instance
- Hydatius's [*Chronicle*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/hydatiuschronicon.html), of the 5th century, has 5 instances

Of course, this analysis assumes that the transcriptions available on Latin Library have not been altered from the originals.  They seem to indicate, however, that *eumdem* was at least occasionally employed in this time period.  Still, many other authors of this time preferred *eundem*: Augustine himself used that form in several other works, and examples of this usage abound in Ammianus, Justinian, and Bede.

## Late Medieval usage

Several prominent authors in the 12th century make extensive use of *eumdem*, perhaps marking a high point of its usage.  They include:

- [Albert of Aix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_of_Aix), author of the [*Historia Hierosolymitanae expeditionis*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/albertofaix.html); over 20 instances of *eumdem*
- [Hugo Falcandus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Falcandus), [*Liber de Regno Sicilie*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/falcandus.html), 7 instances
- [William of Tyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_of_Tyre), [*Historia*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/williamtyre.html), 4 instances in book 20 alone
- [Alanus de Insulis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_de_Lille), [*De Planctu Naturae*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/alanus/alanus1.html), 4 instances

Even in this time period, however, other authors continued to use *eundem*.  The Latin Library includes Aquinas, Gregory VII, Gregory IX, and the Magna Carta in this category, though a more thorough investigation of Aquinas's works reveals a fairly even split between the two forms.

## Modernity

Following the Medieval period, most authors seem to adopt the use of *eundem*.  Among them are Spinoza and Descartes, though Erasmus is a notable exception; his [*Institutes*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/erasmus/inst.shtml), for example, include *eumdem* several times.

## Summary

I don't see any clear patterns of the use of *eumdem*, whether by time or by geography.  Examples of it exist back to at least Late Latin, and it was more widely employed in the late Medieval period.  But it does not appear to have ever achieved dominance over *eundem*.

Comment: Nice, +1. I'll wait a day or two before accepting it. Btw. I remember seeing "eumdem" somewhere in Aquinas, but I don't remember where - but it might have been a "correction" by some later scribe, or even in his homilies, that were only translated to Latin.

Comment: @PavelV. [Here's the Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:www.thelatinlibrary.com+aquinas+eumdem) of Latin library for Aquinas: it finds nothing for eumdem and 8 results for eundem.  So yes, perhaps a transcription error or scribal modification took place.  Unfortunately a really definitive answer would require a corpus of carefully transcribed Medieval manuscripts, and if one of those exists I'm not aware of it.

Comment: For the most comprehensive online collection of Aquinas' works, http://dhspriory.org/thomas/, I found 65 times "eumdem" and [94 times "eundem"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.thelatinlibrary.com%20aquinas%20eumdem&rct=j#q=site:http:%2F%2Fdhspriory.org%2Fthomas%2F+eundem). The Latin Library is good, perhaps the best single site for discerning long-time trends, but they don't have everything.

Comment: for future reference the dhspriory.org content has been taken down but I believe [corpusthomisticum.org](http://corpusthomisticum.org/) is entirely comprehensive in any case.